# Challenges Margaret Thatcher faced as a woman?

Tags: political-history, britain

As the first and only woman who served as Prime minister for Britain, What are some challenges she faced as a woman and how she dealt with them?
Its hard to find correct information about her because half of the population loved her and other half loathed.

Comment: The correct information **is** that half the people loved her & half hated here.  Vote to Close as opinion based.  (You may wish to consult her autobiography).

Comment: The IRON LADY ??? Iron ladies don't have "challenges"; maybe a few petulant ninnies needed to be squashed, but actual challenges? Rubbish!

Comment: I don't think this is too opinion based (unlike the closers), but I won't vote to re-open because it is also overly broad and imprecise. Pick up specific possible challenge and ask if it happened and what examples were.

Comment: people hating or loving her won't affect the basic accuracy of the information you find. For example there was a Falklands War, nobody will pretend there wasn't based on how they feel about her. You can do research even knowing that some of the sources may be overestimating the importance of significance of some parts of the story they're telling (or underestimating, of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think the main challenge she had - *pace* Tyler Durden - was when Argentina invaded the Falkland Islands. No one at the time saw a female PM as a potential war leader - even a little war, and assumed she would opt for negotiation. She didn't. And, whilst I'm in the 50% that loathed her, she was subject to sexist abuse - "hitting people with her handbag" , "grocer's daughter", cartoons with iron spikes for breasts - which no **male** politician would have experienced.

Comment: That's exactly what I said, she had to squash a few petulant ninnies--like Argentina, not really much of a challenge.

Comment: I never knew she was subject to sexist abuse.

Comment: Do you think being only woman in the cabinet made her uncomfortable and her opinions were not valued much by her cabinet members?

Comment: No way, @samadbond! She could have brought women into the cabinet, she preferred to be the only Queen Bee. Climb the ladder, then pull it up behind you!

Comment: @TylerDurden - were you in the UK at the time? Had you been, you might know it was huge - logistically and politically.

Comment: ""My heart always fell when I had to sit next to her." Dealing with Margaret Thatcher face to face was "like feeding a fierce animal", according to Robin Butler, her private secretary"  - doesn't sound like her opinions were not valued, nor does it sound like she was uncomfortable.